# getting the subject of email with php script

Tags: php, email, smtp

I have the following script which is basically run by a cron job to check an e-mail address, get the body of the message and insert it into the database.

I need to alter it to get the subject also, and I can't figure out how... any help would be great.

```
$aHeaders = imap_headers( $hMail );

// get message count
$objMail = imap_mailboxmsginfo( $hMail );

if($objMail != NULL)
{
// process messages
for( $idxMsg = 1; $idxMsg <= $objMail->Nmsgs; $idxMsg++  )
{
    // get header info
    $objHeader = imap_headerinfo( $hMail, $idxMsg );

    // get from object array
    $aFrom = $objHeader->from;


    // process headers
    for( $idx = 0; $idx < count($aFrom); $idx++ )
    {
        // get object
        $objData = $aFrom[ $idx ];

        // get email from
        $strEmailFrom = $objData->mailbox . "@" . $objData->host;

        // do some stuff here


        $bodyMessage = imap_body($hMail,$idxMsg);//displays full
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside the first for loop,

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($objHeader);
echo '</pre>';
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-headerinfo.php

Comment: @Carpetsmoker what does that have to do with the subject?

Comment: A subject may be encoded with an optional charset and transfer encoding. It looks something like this: (top mail in my spambox) `=?iso-8859-1?Q?Semin=E1rio_de_com=E9rcio_exterior:_riscos=2C_parceiros_?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?e_log=EDstica.__=28_20:50:27_=29?=`. That's why you always need to decode the Subject and a bunch of other header fields. See [RFC2047](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2047.html)

Comment: cool, never seen one encoded before... isnt imap fantastic :D

Answer (score 1):

After the line where you get `from`:

```
$objHeader->Subject;
```

Comment: yea just saw @dogmatic69's post.